# Is there a way to make an object behave as a part of the connector for lay-outing purposes in diagram?

Tags: layout, diagram, enterprise-architect, connector

In our project we have modelled dataflows as objects to be able to model dependencies and specializations. So, the data flow between TWO functions is modelled as Function 1 -connector> dataflow object -connector> Function 2.

[image]

This is however a problem in a larger diagram, it becomes cluttered and everything is a mess of objects and connectors and needs to be arranged manually.

So, is there a way to make dataflow object behave as a part of the connector between function objects? I.e. to have same properties for lay-outing as connectors?

I did arrange everything manually, but it is tedious work.

I hope there might be some function to be run on the diagram to align the connectors between prearranged "static" objects, or a way to change importance of the "dataflow object" so it is lower than connector, so when rearranging "functional object" the dataflow object is dragged around with the connector.

Comment: You didn't model dataflows between functions and interfaces, you modelled dataflows from/to data objects. That is a difference. Where you intend to say `Function1->Function2`, you are actually modelling `Function1->DataObject1` and `DataObject1->Function2`. So there is no relation actual relation between Function1 and Function2. What if there is also a  `DataObject1->Function3` and a `Function4->DataObject1`? Which functions are now connected?

Comment: I guess you need to script that layout. Possible but fur sure not an simple one. I did something for port/connectors layout. Worked but it was a "expert" tool (meaans you need to know what to do or getting worse result than before).

Comment: @GeertBellekens thanks for your insight. We have a constraint that dataflow object only connects TWO functions (having one in and one out connector)

Comment: @querty_so thanks, I also think some expert tool is needed, I was just wondering, may somebody had the similar problem ans a solution.

Comment: Have you considered using an InformationFlow connector which can convey one or more information items (such as datasets) https://sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/16.0/modeling_languages/using_information_flows.html

Comment: @SteveFord, thanks for your sugestion. We did, but due to modelling reasons, i.e. data flow hierarchy, we decided against it. Now I am comming to a conclusion that it was a bad decision aiming to support use case which is not that important although seemed important at the time we made the decision :-)